# iPhone, special characters in JSON Response

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, rest

Writing an iPhone app, and I'm getting my data from a REST API that returns JSON. My problem is, some of the data has special characters embedded and I'm getting errors. Example:

```
MartÌn
Petite-RiviËre-Saint-FranÁois
```

Here is my current code:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] 
                            initWithData:receivedData 
                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *tempResults = [[[jsonString JSONValue] 
                            objectForKey:@"getRegionResortsLastUpdatedResponse"] 
                            objectForKey:@"return"];
```

Whenever the data has special characters in it "jsonString" return "(null)", otherwise everything works fine.

Is this something I can handle on my end, or does the API need to be modified to output the character codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `-initWithData:encoding:` returns nil, your data is almost certainly not encoded in the requested encoding. I suspect you're not sending UTF8, and are rather sending some other encoding such as one of the Windows code pages or Latin1. See String Encoding in the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use Following functions to encode your code I did this and works for me perfectly....

```
+ (NSData*) resolveXmlSpecialEntities:(NSData*)xmlData
{
    if (xmlData == nil) 
        return nil;
    if ([xmlData length] == 0)
        return xmlData;

    NSMutableString* xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;quot;" withString:@"\"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"##??##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@"##?!##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;br&gt;" withString:@"##br##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;/br&gt;" withString:@"##/br##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;b&gt;" withString:@"##b##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;/b&gt;" withString:@"##/b##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;center&gt;" withString:@"##center##"options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;/center&gt;" withString:@"##/center##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##??##![CDATA[" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"]]##?!##" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"##ampersand##" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];
    [xmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##ampersand##nbsp;" withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])];

    xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [xmlString release];
    return xmlData;
}

+ (NSString*) stringByRemovingResolversInXmlString:(NSString*)xmlString
{
    NSMutableString* stringToChange = [NSMutableString stringWithString:xmlString];

    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##??##" withString:@"<" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##?!##" withString:@">" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##br##" withString:@"<br>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##/br##" withString:@"</br>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##b##" withString:@"<b>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##/b##" withString:@"</b>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##center##" withString:@"<center>"options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##/center##" withString:@"</center>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];
    [stringToChange replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"##ampersand##" withString:@"&" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToChange length])];

    return [NSString stringWithString:stringToChange];
}
```